# What is the adjoint of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning, adjoint-operators

$A$ is a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix with strictly positive eigenvalues.

Define    $( \cdot ,\cdot) : \mathbb{R}^{ n} \times \mathbb{R}^{ n}  $  $\rightarrow   \mathbb{R}$ by $(x,y) = x' A y$.

Given that $T$ is an arbitary linear operator  $T:   \mathbb{R}^{ n} \times \mathbb{R}^{ n}  $

Could please show me analytically how would you find the adjoint of $T$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $'=^\text{T}$ denotes transposition. The hypothesis on $A$ assure that $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is an inner product and $A$ is invertible.

By definition, $T^\ast$ is defined by : $$(x,Ty)=(T^\ast x,y).$$
We have : $$(x,Ty)=x'ATy=x'ATA^{-1}Ay=[A^{-1}T^\text{T}Ax]'Ay=(A^{-1}T^\text{T}Ax,y),$$
which means : $$T^\ast=A^{-1}T^\text{T}A.$$